# How can I code Riccati-Bessel functions and their derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried my best to code Ricatti-Bessel functions and their derivatives, but I am encountering problems. Please guide me on how to code them?

Comment: Did you see this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riccati-BesselFunctions.html

Anyway, please show what have you already done?

Comment: Basically i have problem in coding of Mathematica for Ricatti bessel functions and their derivatives i have complete visit wolfram web but on it find not exact solution can you help me plz?

Comment: We will not be able to help you unless you show some work you have done and indicate what does not work.

Answer (score 2):

$S_{n}(z)= z j_{n}(z)$

is sufficient. Mathworld is closer to mathematical standard respectively conventions. Mathematica is more Wolfram language style. So both sides of the identity are not part of Mathematica directly.

```
Plot[x SphericalBesselJ[#, x] & /@ Range[5], {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: plot of Ricatti-Bessel function S]

is the Mathematica representation for direct input in the input line.

$C_{n}(z)=-z n_{n}(z)$

is the very same transformation from math into Mathematica.

```
Plot[-x BesselJ[#, x] & /@ Range[5], {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: plot of Ricatti-Bessel function C]

To calculate a derivate is done is Mathematica this way:

```
D[x SphericalBesselJ[#, x] & /@ Range[5], x]
```

[image]

and

```
D[-x BesselJ[#, x] & /@ Range[5], x]
```

[image]

This can be continued for the desired degree of derivative with the documentation of [D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html).

The next step to convert this into mathematical standard notation with

```
D[-x BesselJ[#, x] & /@ Range[5], x]// TraditionalForm
```

[image]

is post-notation. [TraditionalForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html) is relatively mighty as this case shows. The last step remains for the fans of Bessel-Riccatti notation.